# netbeans 8.0.2 not breaking on javascript breakpoints and does not load updated javascript files

Tags: javascript, debugging, netbeans, swap

Maybe someone already answered this but I can't find. I was wondering if anyone came across the issue where break points set in javascript files are not always recognized? Also, in debug mode, when I made a change to the js file that's loaded using "load(filepath)", it does not recognize any change once the eval() is called. Could someone shed some lights on this? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The way that I use breakpoints in JavaScript is by:

```
pressing F12
go to Sources tab
on the left side there is a list of files, 
click on the js file that you want to add the break point to
then add the break point where you want it and then run your code.
```

In this window you can rite-click on a var and add it to watch this is really helpful.

**EDIT**: note that this is in the browser and not in Net Beans, I forgot to mention. Also the tabs names and functionality changes browser to browser. My favorite browser is Chrome. I don't know of any plug-ins to enable break-points in an IDE for JavaScript such as Net Beans, Although that would be cool.

Comment: Check this tutorial, JS debugging is supported since version 7.3 https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-js-support.html